# Passing DataTable as SelectParameters of ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

Is there any procedure to pass DataTable as SelectParameter to ObjectDataSource.

I want to implement this as the datasource for the data control(listview) changes every time depending on the selected value in dropdown or Text changed event occurs in a textbox.

and I'm programatically binding the ObjectDataSource to DataControl.
like

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt=BL.getSelectedValues(ddlFoo.SelectedItem.Value);
ods.SelectParameters.Add("dataTable",dt);
```

Any alternative suggestion will also be useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the `ObjectDataSource` to your `Business` object.

```
public class TestSource
{
   public DataTable GetTestSource()
    {
      .....
      return dataTableObject;
     }
}
```

And markup,

```
 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" 
                       runat="server"
                       SelectMethod="GetTestSource" 
                       TypeName="TestSource">
 </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Or populate ObjectDataSource dynamically,

```
ObjectDataSource ds = new ObjectDataSource();
ds.TypeName = "TestSource";
ds.SelectMethod = "GetTestSource";
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```